# why I got This expression has a type of 'void' so its value can't be used. on my flutter application

Tags: flutter, get, widget, retrofit, display

I want to return a picture using retrofit for my flutter application but on the build Widget I got this error : **This expression has a type of 'void' so its value can't be used.
**
this is my code:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  Future<void> getData() async {
    final dio = Dio();
    final client = ApiService(dio);
    final response = await client.downloadFile();
    WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

    runApp(MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: Image.memory(response.response.data),
        ),
      ),
    ));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<void>(
      future: getData(),
      builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<void> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          return Text(snapshot.data);
        } else {
          return CircularProgressIndicator();
        }
      }
    );
  }
}
```

I want to return the getData() content.

Comment: You're specifying `AsyncSnapshot as <void>` and also your `FutureBuilder as <void>` so it will also return a void

Comment: Your `AsyncSnapshot<void>` expects a `void` result or basically no result, so your `snapshot.data` is a type of `void` but the `Text` widget expects the `String` parameter.

Comment: @AnteBule so how should I fix it !!

Comment: @RisheekMittal how to fix this please

Comment: I don't understand what do you want to return from the `getData()` method

Comment: @RisheekMittal I want to return the picture in the url specifiied on my code

Comment: can you send me the whole code

Comment: I'm not understanding how you're calling the MyApp class and why do you have a runApp function in your getData() function

Comment: It really doesn't make sense to have that `runApp` in the `getData()` function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if it works but maybe you can try this:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  Future<Image> getData() async {
    final dio = Dio();
    final client = ApiService(dio);
    final response = await client.downloadFile();
    return Image.memory(response.response.data);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<Image>(
      future: getData(),
      builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<Image> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          return snapshot.data;
        } else {
          return CircularProgressIndicator();
        }
      }
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: the same problem

Comment: @rania I had a small typo. try again with `AsyncSnapshot<Image>`

Answer (score 0):

Try this once I think this will work for you:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

 Future<dynamic> getData() async {
    final dio = Dio();
    final client = ApiService(dio);
    final response = await client.downloadFile();
    return response.response.data;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<dynamic>(
      future: getData(),
      builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<dynamic> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          return Image.memory(snapshot.data);
        } else {
          return CircularProgressIndicator();
        }
      }
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: it's okay but the pic wasn't displayed

Comment: Can you send me the `response.response.data`? Are you sure you should be using `Image.memory` here and not `Image.Asset`

Comment: Actually I retrieve data from an endpoint  I update my question

Comment: did you update your question? I want to see the response you're getting from the response.response.data query